# Using SoundPool for games

Tags: kotlin, soundpool

```
class SoundPlayer(context: Context) {

// For sound FX
private val soundPool: SoundPool = SoundPool(10, // Here 
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    0)

companion object {
    var playerExplodeID = -1
    var invaderExplodeID = -1
    var shootID = -1
    var damageShelterID = -1
    var uhID = -1
    var ohID = -1
}

init {
    try {
        // Create objects of the 2 required classes
        val assetManager = context.assets
        var descriptor: AssetFileDescriptor


        // Load our fx in memory ready for use
        descriptor = assetManager.openFd("shoot.ogg")
        shootID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0)

        descriptor = assetManager.openFd("invaderexplode.ogg")
        invaderExplodeID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0)

        descriptor = assetManager.openFd("damageshelter.ogg")
        damageShelterID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0)

        descriptor = assetManager.openFd("playerexplode.ogg")
        playerExplodeID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0)

        descriptor = assetManager.openFd("damageshelter.ogg")
        damageShelterID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0)

        descriptor = assetManager.openFd("uh.ogg")
        uhID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0)

        descriptor = assetManager.openFd("oh.ogg")
        ohID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0)


    } catch (e: IOException) {
        // Print an error message to the console
        Log.e("error", "failed to load sound files")
    }
}

fun playSound(id: Int){
    soundPool.play(id, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1f)
}
}
```

i have a problem with SoundPool cant use it is says constructor SoundPool is deprecated 
i'm kinda new so don't know how to fix this (watched many videos and searched everywhere but i cant fix it) 
so maybe someone can help me out tell me what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When something is deprecated, there always should be a hint what to use instead.
So you need to use `SoundPool.Builder` to create new instance of an object.
But there is one issue if you target API level that was release before `SoundPool.Builder` then you will get `ClassNotFoundException`.
So general approach is to check the API level and do things in old way before API X(when new feature was introduced), and a new way after API X:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun buildSoundPool(maxStreams: Int):SoundPool =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val attrs = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .build()
        SoundPool.Builder()
            .setAudioAttributes(attrs)
            .setMaxStreams(maxStreams)
            .build()
    } else {
        SoundPool(maxStreams, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0)
    }
```

Then:

```
private val soundPool: SoundPool = buildSoundPool(10)
```

Also I do recommend to use [my custom implementation of SoundPool](https://gitlab.com/olekdia/common/libraries/sound-pool) because lots of platform dependent issues that was introduced in original SoundPool on different versions on Android.